# Residues odd real function issue

Tags: analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

I'm trying to solve this integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^3}{x^6+1}dx$$

using the residues theorem, but I failed noisily...

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkQ94.jpg), I show the process I've followed, getting 0 as a result.

Thank you in advance,

A.

Comment: You are doing it by residues?  If so, you need to integrate on a closed contour.  What contour do you want to use?

Comment: Your process is intransparent without explanation. Probably, you managed to calculate $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^3}{x^6+1}dx$, and that's $0$ by symmetry. I guess your integral can't be evaluated with residues, immediately, though after a substitution $x=e^u$, it might.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I just posted a solution that uses the residue theorem.  So,  yes if can be done rather easily.

Comment: @ProfessorVector you are right. Ty for the answer.

Comment: @MarkViola, what you've done can always be the way to face problems with odd function evaluated in $(-\infty,\infty)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Almighty This approach applies to the solution to other problems, but does not "always" provide a tractable way forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $C$ be the closed contour in the upper-half plane that is comprised of $(i)$ the straight line segment from $0$ to $R$, $(ii)$ the circular arc from $R$ to $Re^{i\pi/3}$, and the straight line segment from $Re^{i\pi/3}$ to $0$.  Then, we can write

$$\oint_C \frac{z^3}{z^6+1}\,dz=\int_0^R \frac{x^3}{1+x^6}\,dx+\int_0^{\pi/3}\frac{(Re^{i\theta})^3}{(Re^{i\theta})^6+1}\,iRe^{i\theta}\,d\theta+\int_R^0 \frac{-t^3}{t^6+1}\,e^{i\pi/3}\,dt\tag1$$

From the residue theorem, we have for $R>1$

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \frac{z^3}{z^6+1}\,dz&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{z^3}{z^6+1}, z=e^{i\pi/6}\right)\\\\
&=2\pi i \frac{1}{6e^{i\pi/3}}\tag2
\end{align}$$

Letting $R\to\infty$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^3}{1+x^6}\,dx&=\frac{2\pi i}{6e^{i\pi/3}(1+e^{i\pi/3})}\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Yes, it can be done easily... if you know how. :)

Comment: @ProfessorVector Indeed ... as always ;-))

Comment: @Milten Thank you and good catch.  I've edited accordingly.